# What 's wrong with going from $x = \sin^{-1}\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(c-d)^2}}$ to $\sin x \;\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(c-d)^2}=a-b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I got this equation by using the Law of cosines.

$$x = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(c-d)^2}}\right) \tag{1}$$

For my use case, I need to remove all divisions in that formula. I did so by applying sin to dissolve arcsin and then multiplying with the lower half of the fraction. My result is this equation:

$$\sin x \;\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(c-d)^2} = a-b \tag{2}$$

Apparently this is wrong, because solving it for test values results in different results.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  It would help if you were to state the context in which these equations arose.  Also, please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: This should be true as long as the argument of $\arcsin$ is between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: I agree with Peter Foreman, and add that actually the argument of arcsin is always between -1 and 1 because $\sqrt{(a-b)^2+(c-d)^2}\ge\sqrt{(a-b)^2}\ge|a-b|$. Can you give the test values that you talked about?

Comment: If you do not give the data and the test process that led to your conclusion, we can not say what is wrong. I assume that you computed $(\sin x)\cdot\sqrt{(a−b)^2+(c−d)^2}$ and not $\sin(x\cdot\sqrt{(a−b)^2+(c−d)^2})$.